# Expressjs- how to pass value from one method to another

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, angular

I have a rest post api which takes the files from angular2 and uploads it to AWS.

It calls a upload method to store file on AWS. The file object has the location url, I want to pass it back to the calling method to store it in MongoDB.

```
app.post('/s3upload', upload.array('uploads[]',12), function (req, res, next) {
         var filemongo = new FileMongo();
         filemongo.originalname = req.files[0].originalname;
         filemongo._idapt = req.body._idapt;
         filemongo.createddate = Date.now();
    //     console.log(filelocation);         
         filemongo.save(function(err) {
        });
    (res.send(req.files)); 
});
```

upload is called like this

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multers3({
        s3:s3,       
        bucket: 'angular2files',
        key: function (req,file, cb) {
              cb(null, file.originalname); 
  //          filelocation = file.location;    ----> how can I pass this location back to the calling method 
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the req.file? as stated the from the documention of multer you can simply leave the callbck of multer alone and it should pass the information to the next middleware (in your case the router final funciton)

Comment: when I try req.file.originalname in the post method I get the this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined`